# Maps JavaScript Api: How to put a info box on each dynamically created marker with the name of the place, and marker is set with setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-maps-markers

I have a Google Maps JS Api project that it has to return the nearby pharmacy from the user position, radius 2000 m. The returned pharmacy locations, are set to get DROP on the map between 200 ms of each other so that the locations won't drop all in the same time. So far, all is in good order, but when I tried to return some location info when click ing the marker, only one location is saved with the info.

````
<script>
        var marker;
        let iconBase = "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/";
        var userPosition;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
                    showUserDetails(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);
                    initialize();
                }, function (e) {
                    ipLookup();
                });
            } else
                ipLookup();
        });

        function showUserDetails(latitude, longitude, additional) {
            userPosition = {
                lat: latitude,
                lng: longitude
            };
            // userPositionString = latitude + "," + longitude;

            $("#latitude").text(latitude);
            $("#longitude").text(longitude);

            if (typeof additional != "undefined") {
                $("#country").text(additional.country.name);
                $("#city").text(additional.city.name);
                $("#continent").text(additional.continent.name);
            }
        }


        let map;
        let service;
        let infowindow;
        function initialize() {
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            //Map options
            var options = {
                center: userPosition,
                zoom: 14,
                // disableDefaultUI: true,
            }
            //New map
            map = new
                google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);

            var request = {
                location: userPosition,
                radius: '2000',
                query: 'farmacie,spital',
            };

            service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.textSearch(request, callback);;

            function addUserLocationMarker() {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map,
                    draggable: true,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    position: userPosition,
                    icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/grn-pushpin.png"
                });

                marker.addListener("click", toggleBounce);
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: "<h3>Locatia mea ! </h3>"
                });
                marker.addListener('click', function () {
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            }
            addUserLocationMarker();
        }

        let neighborhoods = [];

        function callback(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var place = results[i];
                    // createMarker(results[i]);
                    neighborhoods = results;
                    drop();
                }
            }
        }

        let markers = [];

        function drop() {

            clearMarkers();

            for (let i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
                addMarkerWithTimeout(neighborhoods[i], i * 200);

            }
        }

        function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
            window.setTimeout(() => {
                markers.push(
                   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                       map,
                        position: position.geometry.location,
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,

                    }, 
                    ));
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", () => {
                    infowindow.setContent('<h2>'+ place.name + '</h2>');
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }),
                    marker.addListener("click", toggleBounce)
            }, timeout);
        }

        function addTextBoxInfo(marker) {

        }

        function clearMarkers() {
            for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                markers[i].setMap(null);
            }
            markers = [];
        }

        function toggleBounce() {
            if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
                marker.setAnimation(null);
            } else {
                marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
            }
        }

        function ipLookup() {
            $.get('https://api.userinfo.io/userinfos', function (r) {
                showUserDetails(r.position.latitude, r.position.longitude, r);
            });
        }
    </script>
    ```
    ```
     <script defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=geometry,places&q=farmacie&callback=initMap">
      </script>
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: place is not defined`.  You have a typo in your `addMarkerWithTimeout` function.  `position` is really `place`.  Best to name the argument to the function in a way that makes sense:

```
function addMarkerWithTimeout(place, timeout) {
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map,
      position: place.geometry.location,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,

    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", () => {
        infowindow.setContent('<h2>' + place.name + '</h2>');
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }),
      marker.addListener("click", toggleBounce);
    markers.push(marker);
  }, timeout);
}
```

call it like this:

```
function drop(neighborhoods) {

  clearMarkers();

  for (let i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
    addMarkerWithTimeout(neighborhoods[i], i * 200);

  }
}
```

Passing the response from the Place Service into the `drop` function:

```
function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      // createMarker(results[i]);
      drop(results);
    }
  }
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zu4kjnhr/2/)

[image: screenshot of map with open infowindow]

**code snippet:**

```js
let map;
let service;
let infowindow;
let userPosition = {
  lat: 40.7127753,
  lng: -74.0059728
}

function initialize() {
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  //Map options
  var options = {
    center: userPosition,
    zoom: 15,
    // disableDefaultUI: true,
  }
  //New map
  map = new
  google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);

  var request = {
    location: userPosition,
    radius: '2000',
    query: 'pharmacy',
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.textSearch(request, callback);;

  function addUserLocationMarker() {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map,
      draggable: true,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: userPosition,
      icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/grn-pushpin.png"
    });

    marker.addListener("click", toggleBounce);
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: "<h3>Locatia mea ! </h3>"
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  }
  addUserLocationMarker();
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      // createMarker(results[i]);
      drop(results);
    }
  }
}

let markers = [];

function drop(neighborhoods) {

  clearMarkers();

  for (let i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
    addMarkerWithTimeout(neighborhoods[i], i * 200);

  }
}

function addMarkerWithTimeout(place, timeout) {
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map,
      position: place.geometry.location,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,

    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", () => {
        infowindow.setContent('<h2>' + place.name + '</h2>');
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }),
      marker.addListener("click", toggleBounce);
    markers.push(marker);
  }, timeout);
}

function clearMarkers() {
  for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers = [];
}

function toggleBounce() {
  if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
    marker.setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Place Searches</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize&libraries=places&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```